# Avoid event from bubbling up through the DOM (Parent to Children)

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="dark">
    <div class="window">
    </div>
<div>

$("div.dark").click(function(e){

       e.stopPropagation();
       $('.dark').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

the problem is when I click on the window itself, all is fading out, so I want to make it fadeOut only when I click on the div.dark. Can't figure it out how to do this, stopPropagation() doesn't work.

Comment: Bind to `div.window`, not `div.dark`.

Comment: In your HTML, the class is "darl"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind to inner `div`

```
$("div.dark").click(function(e)
{
       if(e.target === this) $('.dark').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: They **don't** want the `.dark` element to fade out when the `.window` element is clicked.

Comment: now when i click on the dark, nothing happens, but when i click on the window all its closing, great!

Comment: @hello Updated the code. try once again...

Comment: oh well, now works fine, thats what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.stopPropagation()` prevent an event from bubbling up to through the DOM-tree. In your case, you want to prevent the click on a child from triggering a click-event on the parent. To achieve that, you need to attach a click-event listener to the child, and stop the event from propagating. The way you do it, it is already too late, since the event has already reached the element and click-callback has already fired. The only thing you do is prevent the click from bubbling further up the DOM.

To prevent a click on the element with class `window` from triggering a click on the parent, you could attach a click-event listener to that element and in the callback just stop the propagation. I believe your code should work as you expect if you just add this as well:

```
$(".window").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

That way a click on the `window` wont reach the parent, thus not trigger the click-event callback you've attached to the parent.

Comment: But they shouldn't use the `e.stopPropagation()` in their original handler

Comment: @Ian That depends, maybe OP do want to prevent a click on `.dark` from propagating for some reason. Hard to tell without the context.

Comment: That's true, it just seemed like they were expecting `stopPropagation` to work in a specific way, but were using it in the wrong place

Comment: @Ian I agree, that could very well be the case.